# How do I create a hash code for an object with an OR in equals()?

Tags: java, hash, computer-science, hashcode

For example, my class looks like the class below. In equals(), I've defined an equivalence where having one of two ids (or both) being equal results in the entire MyObject.equals() method returning true. Regardless of this being a good thing to do (I've abandoned this approach for a project), I'm *curious* if it is possible to define a hashCode() method that would work correct with the equals() method.

```js
public class MyObject {
    private UUID id;
    private UUID secondaryId;

    public MyObject(UUID id, UUID secondaryId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.secondaryId = secondaryId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MyObject myObject = (MyObject) o;

        // Both id and secondary Id are not null on both objects
        if (id != null && myObject.id != null && secondaryId != null &&
            myObject.secondaryId != null) {

            return id.equals(myObject.id) &&
                   secondaryId.equals(myObject.secondaryId);
        }
        // Id is not null on both objects
        else if (id != null && myObject.id != null) {
            return id.equals(myObject.id);
        }
        // Secondary id is not null on both objects
        else if (secondaryId != null && myObject.secondaryId != null) {
            return secondaryId.equals(myObject.secondaryId);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO: How do write a hashcode that reflects the equals method?
    }
}
```

From my little thought on the manner, it seems very hard to do because you could always be missing data. When you are attempting to match an object with both ids defined with an object with a single id defined I don't see how you would be able to know the truth. The best answer I could come up with would be that in the case where you always had one object with **both** ids defined, you could create a hash that was the combination of two 16-bit hashes for both keys that had a marker between them. So you would always look at the first 16 bits for the first id and then look at the next 16 bits for the second id. That said - I don't have a clue on how to write that approach in a language like Java.

TLDR; **How would you write the hashCode() method?**

Comment: Your `.equals` isn’t transitive:
`MyObject(A,null)==MyObject(A,B)==MyObject(null,B)`, but `MyObject(A,null)!=MyObject(null,B)`.

Comment: `return 0;` works with *any* `equals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There would be no way create a unique hash code for 2 different objects that both "equal" another object.

Quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29):

> The general contract for overridden implementations of this method (hashCode()) is
>   that they behave in a way consistent with the same object's equals()
>   method: that a given object must consistently report the same hash
>   value (unless it is changed so that the new version is no longer
>   considered "equal" to the old), and that two objects which equals()
>   says are equal must report the same hash value.